# Finding change of basis matrix when given two bases as a set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Find the change of basis matrix between the following bases:

$\alpha = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 2 & -3 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$ and  $\beta = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$.

I'm not sure how to do this. I'm confused because I'm given matrices now. I know how to do it when I'm given a set of vectors: then I just have to write them as linear combinations of each other and write the coefficients in the column of a matrix. But what should I do here? If I write $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ as a linear combination of the basis matrices in $\beta$, then I get a $4 \times 4$-matrix, which can't be right?

Comment: For example, $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} = 1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + 1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + (-1) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + 2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Ok, I just write these coefficients in the columns then. But what about the other transition matrix? From $\alpha$ to $\beta$?

Comment: The simplest option is probably to calculate $\beta$ to $\alpha$ transition matrix first, and then invert it. Another option is to ravel matrices into column vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the transition matrix from $\alpha$ to $\beta$: note that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} = 1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + 1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + (-1) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + 2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
So, the first column of the transition matrix will be $(1,1,-1,2)^T$.  Similarly, we may find the other columns so that the transition matrix is given by
$$
[I]_{\alpha \to \beta} = 
\pmatrix{
1&3&1&2\\
1&1&-1&1\\
-1&-1&2&-1\\
2&2&-3&0
}
$$
We then calculate
$$
[I]_{\beta \to \alpha} = ([I]_{\alpha \to \beta})^{-1}
$$